# Setting a soap WSSE Header in powershell

Tags: powershell, soap, wsse

I've been hitting my head against the desk for days with this.

I have to make a soap call using Powershell as i am getting info from Active Directory.

Making the call is not an issue and I hit a mock service with no issue, the issue lies when I hit the real endpoint and it expects a WSSE security header...

I'm using

```
  $wsproxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $wsdl
```

I can find no way to set a header i have tried setting the Credentials individually but it does nothing

```
 $wsproxy.Credentials.Username = "Username"  
 $wsproxy.Credentials.Password = "password"
```

They want the format to be

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasisopen.xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
     soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
  <wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:Username>[user@domain.com]</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password>[password]</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Also tried

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

$wsproxy.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -force))
```

Comment: Have you by any chance come up with a solution. I have the same issue and it seems to me that the serialization of the authentication header is not happening.